# I noticed that my M1 Macs use an Intel process for the screensaver

Tags: big-sur, screensaver, apple-silicon

Whenever I run a screensaver on my M1 Mac, I noticed that this spawns an Intel process called: `legacyScreenSaver-x86_64`.

Anyone else seeing this? I know the entire system (including all the BSD stuff) is universal binary, so it's a little weird this is still intel only.

Anyone else see this?

Comment: Do you have a custom screensaver installed?

Comment: @nohillside hmm I did but removed it, what do you see when you start the system preferences screensaver pane? What process starts for you?

Comment: I get both an ARM and an Intel version of the legacyScreenSaver process, but then I do have some old screensavers around.

Comment: yep seems that's normal